# How can I view my facebook email address?

Tags: facebook

How can I view my facebook email address?

I managed to get to this screen

[image]

from there I scrolled down, and got this screen

Then I chose account settings

[image]

then I get this screen

[image]

and none of these options open up.

I just can't see where i'd be able to see my email address.

**added explanations**

Those screenshots are from my Android Phone, in the Facebook App. (not from a web browser, i'm not logged in in any web browser, and as mentioned I don't have the email address)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your last image, click General, it contains your basic information, like name, email, phone number, networks, and inactive account management person.

The full path to this from the Facebook app is press the 3 line hamburger menu, scroll to the bottom section and find Account Settings, then General.

The way to access this information is exactly the same in the mobile web page.

If they are not opening up, refresh the page or try a different browser.

Also, if you have the Facebook app installed, go to Settings, Accounts, then Facebook, the email address associated with your account is right at the top of the page.

Comment: this is from the app. I am not using a browser I don't have the email address.   I can't see a "settings" option. I see "account settings" which I showed in my screenshots

Comment: If you have the app, you have an entry in Android's account management... Go to your Android device's settings menu {not in the Facebook app), go to Accounts, and open the Facebook entry, the email address is at the top of that page.

Comment: Thanks, You can make that the answer.   If I hadn't been talking about the app then it'd have been more of a web browser issue possibly related to mobile views of webpages and not really an android specific question.  But I was talking about the app and it was an android question and thus your comment there is the answer.

Comment: @barlop That info was in my initial answer, see the last paragraph. :)

Comment: Could've been at the beginning rather than the end.